# SVG textpath doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: text, svg

Attempting to place text along a path.  Example from web but fails on my box:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
    <g>
        <rect style="fill:white;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0;stroke-miterlimit:0;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" width="1000" height="1000" />

        <path id="Geek" fill="yellow" stroke="green" d="M100 900 Q900 900 900 450 Q900 100 500 100 Q100 
                  100 100 400 Q100 700 450 700 Q700 700 750 500" />

        <text>
            <textPath href="#Geek">The Geeky Text Along The Path</textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The path shows but there is no text.

Answer (score 0):

I almost went mad trying to fix this, then fell on this question. I can't believe it's not fixed after a year...
Basically today (18th Feb 2022) neither GIMP nor Image Viewer will display textPath, just use your browser until it's fixed, I tried with Firefox and you can see the text just fine.